# Can I mix 2d and 3d scenes in game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am totally new to Unity and I looked some tutorials and I want to make game which has 3 scenes which are 2d and 2 scenes which are 2d. Is this possible to do or I have to treat all as 3d scenes ? ( I read some books but didn't find or notice solution to this).

Comment: "3 scenes which are 2d and 2 scenes which are 2d"??? one of them must be 3d? no?

Answer (score 13):

There is only one type of scene in Unity3d, which is fundamentally a 3d scene.

You can however put the Scene View into '2d Mode', this helps when working with 2d content. Here's a good introduction video on the 2d Scene View Mode:

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-mode

In reality you can mix and match 2d and 3d within one scene or just have a scene display all it's contents as 2d or 3d. This is down to how you have your camera(s) set-up, using Orthographic Projection on the camera to display as 2d - quite often you'll find that a lot of games have at least two cameras set-up in a scene, one camera for displaying the 3d content and a second (Orthographic) camera for displaying the 2d UI.

Answer (score 4):

All Unity scenes are 3D. The 2d function only changes the view of the game to 2D, but under the hood everything is still 3D.

You can have different 'UnityScenes' with different modes. Like a 2d minigame whilst the game loads and then goes into the next scene in 3D.

If you want to use different perspectives in 1 UnityScene however you can do that also, but you need to adjust the camera because that will always be 3D. There are assets which can easily do this for you however, just browse the asset store for 'free top-down camera' or perhaps even '2d camera' will work.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any difference between 2d scene and 3d scenes and they are all called Scene in Unity and have even the same code.
In fact 2d Scenes are 3d Scene with Camera set to Orthographic instead of Perspective view.